# JDBC kinds of connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm creating app for library management with Java and MySQL ( JDBC to connect with DB ) , and I have a problem , I checked a lot of topics, books, and websites but I didn't find good answer for me. Is it the good way to deal with connections ? I think that one connection for entire app is good option in this case. My idea is that in every function in every class when I need to use Connection object , these functions will need a connection parameter. In main class I'll call manager object 'Man' for example and to every constructor etc I'll pass `Man.getMyConn()` as this parameter and call `Man.close()` when Main frame will be closed . Is it bad idea ? Maybe I should use singleton pattern or connection pool ? 
Sorry for my English , I'm still learning.

```
public class manager {
private Connection myConn;

public manager() throws Exception {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream("app.properties"));

    String user = props.getProperty("user");
    String password = props.getProperty("password");
    String dburl = props.getProperty("dburl");


    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);
    System.out.println("DB connection successful to: " + dburl);
}

public Connection getMyConn() {
    return myConn;
}
  //close class etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually not. Further answer depends on type of the application. If you're making web application then you should definitely go with connection pool. If you're making e.g. desktop application (where only one user can access it at the time), then you can open and close connection upon each request.

Comment: It'll be desktop app. So I should create class getConnection which returns new Connection object and every time I need to execute query etc. Should I use it ? In try clause with resources for example because I don't need to worry about closing connections,statements etc. am I right ? return should look  Like this : "return DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);" ? Thanks for help

Comment: Close them all in `finally` (very important!) block. Connection, statements, result set instances... As I said upon each database request, you will open a new connection (and close it after the query or statement are executed).

Comment: Since it's a desktop app you will be distributing the database URL, user ID, and password.  Do you trust all of the users to behave?

Comment: @AndrewS That's inevitable. You simply have to trust them. Doing some funky stuff like encoding DB arguments leads nowhere :)

Comment: Well, either you trust them, or you don't access the database directly. It's a pretty poor idea to access a database over the *public* internet. It's better to use something else for the communication and have a server perform the actual database actions. If you're the only user of the database (and you don't have a proper server-client architecture), then there's no need to close the connection after every operation either.

Answer (score 0):

I have working applications that do it your way. As @Branislav says, it's not adequate if you want to do multiple concurrent queries. There's also a danger that the connection to the database might be lost, and you would need to restart your application to get a new one, unless you write code to catch that and recreate the connection.

Using a singleton would be overcomplicated. Having a `getConnection()` method (as you have done) is very important as it means you can easily change your code to use a pool later if you find you need to.

Comment: But in that case getConnection() should return a new connection every time I call this function yes ? Or like at my app getConnection() should return existing connection and when i want to have more connections i can just create more managers objects and everyone of them has own connection am I right ? Which i can access by obj1.grtmyconn(),obj2.grtmyconn etc. Yes ?